# Error response from daemon: No such image: localstack/localstack:0.14.0

Tags: go, gitlab-ci

Recently I had this error
`Error response from daemon: No such image: localstack/localstack:0.14.0`
when setting up gnomock.
I was getting the error on this line

```
gmock, err = gnomock.Start(preset, gnomock.WithDebugMode(), gnomock.WithUseLocalImagesFirst())
```

The test is passing when I test on my machine, but when ran on gitlab's runners it was throwing the error I mention above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was to clear the cache of the runners.**

The internet do not say much about this error. My theory is that because the mock was used in a sub package of the project (wrapped around), labstack got an update, and somehow that did not prop the docker images correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer to the problem you had. It may be useful to include your job `cache:` configuration that was causing the issue.